# How to make a bootable usb drive from multi-disk installers, e.g. Windows Recovery Disks?

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, usb, dvd

I have an HP laptop with Windows 7 OEM. I have created a 3 DVD (4.7GB) recovery disks using the wizard inside Windows and I have used it several times to restore my system back and working.

However, last week I have figured out that my DVD drive is failing and I cannot use these disks to recover my system. I can create a USB disk from the first DVD, however, at the middle of setup, the installer asks for the second disk.

Put it short, Is there any way to create a USB disk from 3 DVDs?

Thanks

Comment: What tool did you use exactly?  Because what you used is a standard feature of Windows.

Comment: what exactly is the problem ? when the installer asks for the second disk, why can't you put the replace the first disk with the second ?

Comment: To create the DVDs, I have used the standard windows tool. However, when I lost all my partitions on hard drive, as well as a not-working DVD drive, I've tried to create a USB disk from the DVDs. However, I was not successful in doing that.

Comment: I have tried doing what you want with HP recovery media and have never been successful yet. Use a DVD usb drive.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a USB disk will only create one disk at a time. To be able to switch between them you need to use separate USB devices or merge the ISOs together for a larger USB disk.

Merging has its own problems if there is a single disk Id file with say 'Disk 1' because you can't have it saying disk 1 2 and 3 all at the same time. If the recovery option allows you to specify the disk drive to use during each disk selection you could always portion your USB into multiple partitions to give the separate drives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this does not work. I have tried it. Maybe I shall use an external DVD drive to restore the system or ask someone to fix my own drive :(.

Comment: To be honest you can buy a USB 3.0 Blu-Ray DVD drive for next to nothing which should work with most systems.